# Angular JS $injector - get dependencies

Tags: angularjs

I need to get the instances of my Services/Factory in my Angular JS application. For that reason I would want to use $injector so as to get instances and not depend on DI. I tried to create a wrapper method over $injector which is a seperate js file so that any other modules can call this helper method and get necessary instances. I know this is not straight forward but still wanted to try.

For this my code looks like

```
//helper.js file

export default function returnInstances(service) {
  const app = angular.module('moduleName');
  let instance; 
  app.run(() => {
    injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'moduleName']);
    instance = injector.get(service);
  });
  return instance;
}

// some other file
const instance = returnInstances('serviceName');
```

As expected this does not work. So I was wondering if anything like this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
const helper = {
  init: (injector) => this.injector = injector;
  get: (name) => this.injector.get(name);
}

export default helper;
```

And in file where you bootstrap your module:

```
app.run((['$injector'], $injector) => helper.init($injector));
angular.bootstrap(...
```

And then u can use it.